# RAM update (MotherBoard: 0Y2MRG)

Tags: memory, motherboard, compatibility

I can't find any info about What RAM are compatible with my MotherBoard.

I've got a Dell 0Y2MRG MotherBoard (Default in my Vostro 460). I would like to upgrade my old 4Go (2*2Go) RAM to 12Go (2*2Go + 2*4Go).

Currently installed are the default (info from speccy):

```
Type    DDR3
Size    2048 MBytes
Manufacturer    Samsung
Max Bandwidth   PC3-10700 (667 MHz)
Part Number M378B5773CH0-CH9
Serial Number   290092519
Week/year   48 / 11
```

Info from windows TaskManager (translated from french):

```
Speed : 1333 MHz
Space Used : 2 of 4
Type : SODIMM
```

So is it 667 or 1333 (I can't find any ram with 667)?

And [Crucial website](http://www.crucial.fr/fra/fr/mise-a-niveau-compatible-avec//vostro-460-mini-tower) tell me the "compatible" RAM but there are UDIMM.
So Is it UDIMM or SODIMM?

Can you, please, confirm that there are compatible (Crucials ones)?

Previous answer from Hardware Recomendations:

> @0-60FPS: What cpu are you using?
>
> @NZKshatriya: From what I have read [here](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/desktop/f/3514/t/19476362), your board can support up to 32Gb/Go of ram, you should read the article to find out the reason why the official documentation shows 16Gb/Go as the upper limit. When they say UDIMM, it just means unregistered memory as opposed to registered. So standard DIMM modules. Personally I would recommend G.Skill as opposed to Crucial.. G.Skill has the best warranty lifetime, transferable and a no nonsense return policy,
>
> My Answer: Hello, Thak you fr your interest. @0-60FPS I've got a i7-2600 CPU. @NZKshatriya I think that for my use (and regarding the age of my computer) I just need 8Go more. G.Skill RAM Configurator Doesn't show Dell as manufacturer.

Comment: UDIMMs is non-ECC memory.  SODIMM are about half the size of UDIMMs.  You should confirm this yourself by looking at the module itself, but the `M378B5773CH0-CH9` are UDIMMs, based on their specification document.

Comment: It's strange you could get the information from the taskmanager in windows. As the mainboard lookslike, it uses DIMM.  https://www.amazon.fr/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?__mk_fr_FR=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=4+gb+dimm+240+pin+ddr3

Comment: @GiaRui in windows 10 task Manager, Memory Panel you got those informations :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why SODIMM is even being contemplated, considering it's a desktop PC. The [manual](http://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_desktop/esuprt_vostro_desktop/vostro-460_setup%20guide_en-us.pdf) says four DIMM slots, 1333 MHz DDR3, with module capacity of 1 GB, 2 GB or 4 GB.

As far as the max bandwidth of 667 MHz not matching 1333 MHz, is because you have to multiply the 667 by 2. This is because DDR stands for Double Data Rate. This means that the RAM can send two signals per clock cycle.

So your configuration of 2x2GB and 2x4GB will work, as long as it's DDR3 1333 MHz, or a lower MHz of course.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I continue this thread on [Hardware Recommendations](http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/6692/ram-update-motherboard-0y2mrg) to get users advice about three RAM I choosed.